# Spring Security Role Hierarchy Not Working

Tags: spring-security

I am attempting to use Spring Security to secure methods using a role hierarchy. Obviously, since I'm posting here, it isn't working.

First, here's a definition from an interface:

```
@PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated()")
List<RetainUser> getByLocation(String location);
```

Next, here's the Unit Test I'm trying to use to test it:

```
@Test
public void getByLocation_anonymousUser_throwsAccessDeniedException() {

    AppUser anonymousUser = (AppUser) retainUserManager.loadUserByUsername("1111");

    Authentication auth = provider.authenticate(new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(anonymousUser, new AppAuthority(anonymousUser, "ROLE_ANONYMOUS")));
    SecurityContext context = new SecurityContextImpl();
    context.setAuthentication(auth);

    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);

    try {
        List<AppUser> testResult = appUserManager.getByLocation("DAYTON");
        fail("call by anonymous user should have thrown AccessDeniedException");
    } catch (AccessDeniedException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Finally, my security.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="methodSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
</security:global-method-security>

<bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="roleHierarchy" ref="roleHierarchy" />
</bean>

<bean id="methodSecurityExpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="roleHierarchy" ref="roleHierarchy" />
</bean>

<!-- In order to use a role hierarchy with the Security expressions, the 
    hierarchy needs to be injected into the expression handler -->


<!-- Configure static resources to have no Spring Security filters applied 
    to them -->
<security:http pattern="/common/**" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/**/*.png" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/styles/**/*.css" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/**/*.css" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/**/*.js" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/login.jsp" security="none" />

<security:http use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/accountWizard.html"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">

    <security:anonymous />
    <security:x509 subject-principal-regex="CN=(.*?)," user-service-ref="retainUserManager" />
        <!-- Role Anonymous needs to be able to hit the index controller in order to be -->
        <!-- redirected to the account wizard (if necessary) -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.html*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/acceptTerms.html*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/accountWizardHome.html*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/accountPending.html*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')"/>
        <!-- Since roles are hierarchal, ROLE_FIELD and above are legal -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.html" access="hasRole('ROLE_FIELD')" />
    <security:session-management>
        <security:concurrency-control
            max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
    </security:session-management>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="appUserManager" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <property name="decisionVoters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="webExpressionVoter" />
            <ref bean="roleHierarchyVoter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="webExpressionVoter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter">
    <property name="expressionHandler">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler">
            <property name="roleHierarchy" ref="roleHierarchy" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="roleHierarchyVoter"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleHierarchyVoter">
    <constructor-arg ref="roleHierarchy" />
</bean>

<bean id="roleHierarchy"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
    <property name="hierarchy">
        <value>
            ROLE_SYSTEM > ROLE_MANAGER
            ROLE_MANAGER > ROLE_FIELD
            ROLE_FIELD > ROLE_ANONYMOUS
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="authenticationEntryPoint" />
    <property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="accessDeniedHandler" />
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.jsp" />
    <property name="forceHttps" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
    <property name="errorPage" value="/403.jsp" />
</bean>
```

In the test above, I'm expecting an AccessDeniedException since the expression is "hasRole('ROLE_FIELD')", which outranks ROLE_ANONYMOUS. Unfortunately, the exception isn't thrown.

Can anyone help?